# Delayed blur-filter with transition in CSS3

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I need to do first a faded blur on a element with a delay of the transition after loading. Second another element should be faded in. I'm using animate.css.

I'm using animate.css.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="main">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="target" class="blur>This element has a background-image, which should be blured</div>
        </div>
        <div class="content-layer">
            <input id="searchMain" class="animated fadeIn delay">
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.blur {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
       -moz-filter: blur(5px);
        -ms-filter: blur(5px);
         -o-filter: blur(5px);
            filter: blur(5px);

    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
       -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
         -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
            transition: all 0.5s linear;

    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
            transition-delay: 1s;
}
.delay {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
       -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
            animation-delay: 1s;
}
```

With this, the delayed fade-in of the inputField works great. The `target` gets also blurred. But this blur is not animated and not delayed.

Comment: You are either not showing us the full code (or) your understanding of transitions is incorrect. There is no state change for a transition to happen on the `target`. Animations on the other hand don't need a state change and can start automatically.

Comment: Ok, you are right: It seems, that I don't understand transitions. So what do I have to change to do it in a correct way? The animation of the input box works, so I thought, that I do the same thing for the blur...

Comment: So are you looking for an animation on page load where the element blurs after a delay of 1s?

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman: CSS3 is still CSS and there was no need to remove that tag.

Comment: @Harry: Yes, correct. I want to do a faded blur after pageload with a delay of 1s.

Comment: Ok, I can help you with writing a pure CSS version of it without using animate.css (because I've never used that). Would that be ok?

Comment: @Harry But this problem related to css3 feature which is not available in old css.

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman: CSS3 is only a module of CSS and all CSS3 features are also in essence CSS only. Removal of other version specific CSS tags (if they had existed) would be no problem.

Comment: @Harry: Yes, would be great

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the code in question was adding a `transition` and a `transition-delay` to the `target` element but there was no change of state for a transition to happen.

Transition can happen only when there is a change of state either due to user interaction like `:hover`, `:focus` etc or due to scripting like addition of a class on click or time out etc. Hence, transitions are not suited for your purpose and you should consider using `animation` instead. Animations can start automatically on page load unlike `transition`.

For an element to be blurred after a 1s delay on page load, set the original state of the element to the unblurred state and then animate it `to` the blurred state like in the below snippet.

```css
#target{
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/100);
}
.blur {
  -webkit-animation: blur 0.5s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation: blur 0.5s linear forwards;
  -ms-animation: blur 0.5s linear forwards;
  -o-animation: blur 0.5s linear forwards;
  animation: blur 0.5s linear forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.delay {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes blur {
  to {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes blur {
  to {
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
  }
}
@keyframes blur {
  to {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
    -moz-filter: blur(5px);
    filter: blur(5px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="target" class="blur">This element has a background-image, which should be blured</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content-layer">
    <input id="searchMain" class="animated fadeIn delay">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're not specifically asking for a CSS/HTML only solution, here's a way to get what you want by adding some jquery to the mix.

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="target" class=">This element has a background-image, which should be blured</div><!-- Start without classes -->
    </div>
    <div class="content-layer">
        <input id="searchMain" class="animated fadeIn delay"> 
    </div>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" defer>
    $(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log('done waiting!'); // Just to verify the delay works
            $('#target').addClass('blur');
        }, 1000); // A delay of 1000ms
    });
</script>
```

Needless to say, make sure the animations are working as you want them. This is just for the delay, after pageload. From here it's pretty easy to build upon that aswell. Like adding the animation when the user has scrolled to the element, etc. etc.

**Updated for #target**

Comment: The animation of the input field was already working (without any scripts) with a delay (see delay-class). The problem is delaying the blur effect to `.target`.

Comment: Just updated the code so it adds the blur after 1 second to `#target`. I misunderstood that part. The solution is the same though.